# Can I use an exiting type/interface on function declaration?

Tags: typescript

I want to use React's type definition for functional component like the following:

```
const SearchItem: React.FC<ISearchItemProps> = props => {}

SearchItem.name // ''
```

To make `SearchItem` a named function, I can do:

```
const SearchItem: React.FC<ISearchItemProps> = function SearchItem(props) {}

SearchItem.name // 'SearchItem'
```

but this requires duplicating the name.

Is there a way to specify a type on function declaration? E.g.:

```
function SearchItem/* React.FC<ISearchItemProps> */(props) {}
```

Comment: Hym, interesting. Can you show where do you use SearchItem. As I just took a look and I see a name. If you use it like <SearchItem /> name should be visible.

Comment: Alternatively you can do `function SomeComponent(props: React.PropsWithChildren<YourProps>) {}` but as I mentioned I dont see the orginal problem

Comment: @MaciejSikora the question is about TypeScript, I've used React code to provide an example.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to duplicate *something*, because TypeScript [doesn't currently let you annotate a function statement with a type of the whole function (see microsoft/TypeScript#22063)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063).  Instead you have to annotate the parameters and return type separately.  The following is the tersest I can be, using the standard [`Parameters`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1496) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility types:

```
type RFC = React.FC<ISearchItemProps>;
function SearchItem(...args: Parameters<RFC>): ReturnType<RFC> {
    return null!; // or whatever it's supposed to return
}

console.log(SearchItem.name) // SearchItem
```

That's probably worse than your original `const SearchItem:... = function SearchItem(...)` syntax, so I'd probably suggest you stick with that.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUDAJ5hZwCSAyjlLgBYcYWEAAViYdAF44AbziM4SlAC44qGFGAA7AOb0GAX0Ys2mAGIBhODOx4YAOisAebrwFCR4iJIB8BggBXbXxgCG04HmQ+QWEQAAoHJOjdVDVRaOQQLGEoVGcMK18ASjVsGECobQAVViwCorlFZUoKqrhtQIAbLoBCA2MGRlxw1AgurAcuiF14qJjPEAdtLKxiuAB6Dcj3WJEgA)

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple way for this, you just need to do it this way:

```
function SearchItem(props): React.FC<ISearchItemProps> {}
```

It means that your function will have a return value of type `React.FC<ISearchItemProps>`

[Edit]: Irrelevant answer - issue was misunderstood

Comment: That would mean that `SearchItem` will _return_ a component, which is not my intent.

Comment: Looking at this line of code `const SearchItem: React.FC<ISearchItemProps> = function SearchItem(props) {}`, I was assuming that your implementation of `SearchItem(props) {}` would return a FC as it is the type your const `SearchItem` is expecting. Wasn't that the case?

Comment: Nope, `SearchItem` is an `React.FC<ISearchItemProps>`, not a function that returns `React.FC<ISearchItemProps>`.